# retrieving ajax array data in php

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var selected = new Array();
    function inviteUser()
    {
         $(document.getElementById('invite')).click(function () 
         {
           getSelectedUsers();
           var movieTitle = document.getElementById('titleKeyword').value;
           var movieID = document.getElementById('movieMid').value;
           var location = document.getElementById('location').value;
           $.ajax({ 
           url: 'processinvitationrequest.php',
            data: {action: 'inviteUser', selectedUsers: selected, movieID: movieID,                  movieTitle: movieTitle, location: location},
           type: 'post',
       success: function(output) 
         {
           alert(output);
         }
      });
    });
   }
function getSelectedUsers() 
{
  $("input:checkbox[name=type]:checked").each(function() {
  selected.push($(this).val());
 });
 }
 </script>
```

i'm trying to send all the values in my checkbox field to a php page for query my db. here is my problem:
1) I don't know if sending the js array 'selected' via the data param is in the correct syntax.
2) How do i retrieve my array from ajax in my php, is my code below correct.

I get a undefined index error.

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action']))
{
$action = $_POST['action'];
switch($action) {
    case 'inviteUser' : inviteUser();break;
}   
function inviteUser()
{
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) 
{
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}
foreach($_POST['selectedUsers'] as $selected)
{
    $notificationLink = "http://localhost/Movies/movienightout.php?movieID=".$_POST['movieID']."&movieTitle=".$_POST['movieTitle']."&location=".$_POST['location']."";
    $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO requestnightout (sender, recipient, notification) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_SESSION['MM_sessionEmail'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['selectedUsers'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($notificationLink, "text"));

    mysql_select_db($database_movie, $movie);
    $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $movie) or die(mysql_error());
    $urlplus="notification=Invitation Sent";
    header("Location: usersocialpage.php?".$urlplus."");
}
 }
```

output:

```
array (size=4)
'action' => string 'inviteUser' (length=10)
'movieID' => string '9' (length=1)
'movieTitle' => string 'Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith 3D' (length=47)
 'location' => string 'seee' (length=4)

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: selectedUsers in C:\wamp\www\Movies\processinvitationrequest.php on line 54
```

Comment: In which line it is showing `undefined index error.`

Comment: Can you try to print `$_REQUEST` on the top of the PHP page.

Comment: foreach($_POST['selectedUsers'] as $selected)  undefined index selectedUsers

Comment: Can you print `data` object in client and send here, so that I can look into the data. Also please try to print `$_REQUEST` on top of the php page and send the output here.

Comment: array (size=4)
  'action' => string 'inviteUser' (length=10)
  'movieID' => string '9' (length=1)
  'movieTitle' => string 'Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith 3D' (length=47)
  'location' => string 'seee' (length=4)

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: selectedUsers in C:\wamp\www\Movies\processinvitationrequest.php on line 54

Comment: wooow it doesnt send my selectedUsers values.

Comment: Check `getSelectedUsers` pushing items or not!

Comment: `$('input[name="type"]:checked').each(function() {
   console.log(this.value);
});`
Check this!!!

Comment: function getSelectedUsers() 
{
  $('#div3 input:checked').each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).attr('value'));
 });
}  i used this and it work